MSI Authentication failed in Azure Machine Learning Online endpoint deployment
I'm trying to deploy a managed online endpoint on Azure Machine Learning workspace but I'm having a MSI authentication problem when trying to authenticate with my workspace from my score.py script using managed-identities. I have checked if my workspace identity is a system-managed assigned identity and yes it is also having its tenant ID. This is the main cause of the error from the deployment logs:
raise AzureResponseError('Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.\n'
azureml._vendor.azure_cli_core.azclierror.AzureResponseError: AzureResponseError:
    Message: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
Get Token request returned: <Response [405]>
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.\nGet Token request returned: <Response [405]>"
    }
}

This is the part of the code in the score script that is performing this action
auth = MsiAuthentication()
    
global model
ws = Workspace.get(
    name = "<workspace_name>",
    subscription_id = "<subscription_id>",
    resource_group = "<resource_group_name>",
    auth = auth
)
logger.info("Found Workspace! Loading model...")
    
model_name = "<model_name>"
model = Model(ws, model_name, version=1)
logger.info("Model loaded.....")


Please include more details like code you tried by editing your question

I've edited it @Sridevi


Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.\nGet Token request returned: <Response [405]>

According to this MS-Document,
Both system and user managed identity is not supported with ManagedIdentityCredential in the local environment.
In my environment, I created azure machine learning with system managed identity.
I get the prinicipal id from the below command to assign role.
Command and output:
 az resource show --resource-group xxx--name xxx --resource-type "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces" --query identity

{
  "principalId": xxx",
  "tenantId": "xxxx",
  "type": "SystemAssigned",
  "userAssignedIdentities": null
}

And I assigned contributor role to that principal id to authenticate with azure machine learning workspace.
Command:
az role assignment create --assignee "xxx" --role "Contributor" --scope "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/vxxxx"

Now I tried with same code to authenticate with system-managed identity in the Azure Machine learning workspace it executed successfully.
Code:
from azureml.core.authentication import MsiAuthentication
from azureml.core import Workspace


msi_auth = MsiAuthentication()

ws = Workspace(subscription_id="xxxx",
                  resource_group="vxxxx",
                  workspace_name="xxxt",
                  auth=msi_auth)

print("Found workspace {} at location {}".format(ws.name, ws.location))

Output:
Found workspace samplevenkat at location centralus


Reference:
Set up service authentication - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn
